# How to exclude script on certain routes in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt2-webapp with a lot of routes and for all routes except 2, I need a script to be injected. Is there a way to disable the injecting?

Nuxt config:

```js
meta: [
  script: [
    {
      id: 'Cookiebot',
      src: 'https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js',
      'data-cbid': 'xxxxx',
      type: 'text/javascript',
      async: true,
    },
  ],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do so.
If you inject a script, it will be on the `window` object. Hence available everywhere in your DOM.

What's the issue with that? You could hide your thing with some CSS if it's annoying visually.

Comment: ah snap...

The issue is that we want certain pages to be embed-able without any third-party scripts or cookies and cookiebot for example is setting those. (also its kinda a performance-topic, because we want to the pages to be blazing fast and therefor we need the page to be as slim as possible

Comment: Oh, you want to have an iframe of your website put into another one? But without the cookie on this specific path? AFAIK, cookies are domain specific and not path specific so I you have some of them somewhere in your website, it's basically all of them everywhere @PeterHauer

Comment: yeah exactly.

The embedded pages are completely independent of cookies and if you embed a website on your own website you need to include their cookies in your cookie-declaration which is not that nice when you want to sell your embeds.

Comment: This could maybe be solved with some nice and smooth CSS. It's always annoying anyway yeah. Maybe just create something totally separate for those 2 page embeds? @PeterHauer

Comment: haha seperating those pages would be the next step :D

thx for your help!

Comment: I just posted a solution for this problem, in case you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this behaviour is via a plugin:

```
export default (context: Context) => {
  if (!context.route.name?.includes('embed')) {
    const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.id = 'Cookiebot';
    scriptTag.src = 'https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js';
    scriptTag.setAttribute('data-cbid', 'xxxx');
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptTag.async = true;
    document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
  }
};
```